# Sonarcloud + Travis fails for custom C quality profile

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I've setup a build job in Travis with the Sonarcloud plugin so that it analyzes one of our C/C++ projects, links:

GitHub source - https://github.com/inilabs/libcaer

Travis job - https://travis-ci.org/inilabs/libcaer/jobs/247488797

Sonarcloud - https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=com.inilabs.libcaer

Now if I run this with the default C quality profile "Sonar way" it works fine. Then I created a test profile where I added a one rule and deleted another, and this also worked, so basic custom quality profiles seem to work fine. Then I created our main quality profile "inilabs" that I want to use, where many more rules are enabled (~50) and several (~10) are disabled. Surprisingly this build fails during the 'sonar-scanner' step, with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher
```

(see the above linked build for full error, run with 'sonar-scanner -X)
It seems to get the files with the custom quality profiles fine, so the only thing I can think of is that there must be a specific rule in one of the ~60 changes that makes this fail, but I have no clue how to debug this to understand which one it is. I hope you can help me in pinpointing the problem, thanks!

Comment: We are currently taking a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! In the meantime I've also added Travis/Sonar support to one of our Java projects, and am seeing the same failure there with the Maven sonar:sonar target: https://travis-ci.org/inilabs/jfxaer/jobs/247556760 but for Java I'm still using the default "Sonar way" profile.

Comment: I've also tried deleting the Sonarcloud project as well as the Travis caches, and regenerating everything, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to some deactivations of rules in your Quality profile, for example see "restrict should not be used" in the changelog: https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/inilabs-github/quality_profiles/changelog?language=c&name=inilabs.

This bug is tracked in https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9489 and will be fixed as soon as possible.

A workaround is to copy the profile to another one. Corrupted rules won't be copied.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and competent support!

Comment: Hi @llongi for your information the fix has been applied to SonarCloud !